# Any solution for a colour-restricted glow?

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes

Hi fellas my problem is that I need to glow only part of a scene and dunno how to. As You could see here...

[image]

...the white cube glows and blue not and I need the exact opposite result. For best I need to respect/glow only the colour of my choice because in original scene I have an alpha-texture like and LCD raster so the object is visible only every now and then (the EVE could be a good example but I have full-black and full-white parts).

[image]

THX in advance for tips!

*Sincerely, Jan*

[image]

Comment: I withdrew my answer.  I misunderstood your question.

Comment: It seems to me that I would put the blue cube on a separate layer, create two render layers, apply the glow filter to the cube layer and mix the two.  The thing I can't figure out / remember how to do is use the white cube as a mask so the fog only hangs over the visible areas of the blue cube.

Comment: Yep, thats the problem I have Marty. Also used the separate layer but when its something in front of the eyes the problem appears.

Comment: I'll dig through my notes some more. There is definitely a way to create a mask from the white object that prevent the glow coming from the hidden face.  I just can't recall how I did it, or find an example in my .blend files